# Print a list of indices then a list of values, stacking them

Tags: for-loop, indexing, python-3.3

```
seq1_values = [5, 40, 180, 13, 30, 20, 25, 24, 29,  31,  54, 46,  42, 50,  67, 17,
           76, 33, 84, 35, 100, 37, 110, 32, 112, 15, 123, 3, 130, 42]

def get_num_values():
    global seq1_values
    return len( seq1_values )

def get_values():
    global seq1_values
    for value in seq1_values:
        yield value
    yield None

def next_value():
    return next( next_value.values )
next_value.values = get_values()


def main():
    numbers = []
    value = next_value()
    while value is not None:
        numbers.append(value)
        input_size = len(numbers)-1
        for i in range(len(str(value))):
            print("|", str(input_size).rjust(4), sep ="", end="")
        for j in range(len(str(input_size))):
            print("|", str(value).rjust(4), sep="", end="")
            value = next_value()
main()
```

The problem is in my for loops, not sure whats wrong. I've tried multiple variations of arguments in the loops. Also its printing the output on one line instead of stacking them.

The output should look like this:

```
|   0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25| 26| 27| 28| 29|
|   5| 40|180| 13| 30| 20| 25| 24| 29| 31| 54| 46| 42| 50| 67| 17| 76| 33| 84| 35|100| 37|110| 32|112| 15|123|  3|130| 42|
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19217203/198633)? What's wrong with the answer you got there?